# Using Factory Method pattern for different arguments

Tags: c++, design-patterns, solid-principles

Hello my question is regarding if its possible to use the factory pattern for classes with same number of arguments in their constructor but different types. For example, I have an interface called **IVerify**. I have 2 classes that implement them, **NameVerifier**, which takes in a **String name** in its constructor,  and **IntegerVerifier**, which takes in an **int num** in its constructor. Is it possible to do the factory pattern in this case?

Could we use **IVerify Factory.CreateNameVerifier(string)**   and **IVerify Factory.createIntegerVerifier(int)** Is it still considered as a factory pattern?

Additional note: Im using c++

Comment: Seems to me that you are injecting runtime values (probably the values you wish to validate) into the constructors of your components (the validators). This is a bad idea, as [explained here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many versions of `NameVerifier` and `IntegerVerifier` then your solution is still a Factory Pattern since you will be abstracting which class to instantiate inside `CreateNameVerifier` and `CreateIntegerVerifier`.

But if `Verifiers` are unique w.r.t to the type of Argument that they take i.e., there is only one `NameVerifier` and only one `IntergerVerifier` and they differ because of their types then your existing solution is just creating a sort of wrapper to create objects/`Verifiers`. In such case it should be something like this:

Reference: [Factory Pattern](http://www.javatpoint.com/factory-method-design-pattern)

```
class IVerify
{
};

class CNameVerifier : public IVerify
{
};

class CIntegerVerifier : public IVerify
{
};

class CVerifierFactory
{
    enum TYPE
    {
        STRING,
        INTEGER
    };

    template<typename T>
    IVerify* CreateVerifier(const CVerifierFactory::TYPE &_enumType, T _Parameter)
    {
        IVerify *pVerifier = NULL;
        switch(_enumType)       
        {
            case (CVerifierFactory::STRING)
                pVerifier = new CNameVerifier(_Parameter);
                break;
            case (CVerifierFactory::INTEGER)
                pVerifier = new CIntegerVerifier(_Parameter);
                break;              
        }

        return pVerifier;
    }   
};

CVerifierFactory g_oFactory;
IVerify *pVerifier = g_oFactory.CreateVerifier(CVerifierFactory::STRING, "Alex");
if(pVerifier != NULL)
{
    //use pVerifier
}
```

***Note:*** Strict Type Checking of arguments `_Parameter` are not done before creating `Verifiers`. You can extend the number of arguments for object creation using [Variadic Template/Parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).